# Finding sides of a quadrilateral given all angles and one side

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

Please help me in finding side of a quadrilateral if one side and all angles are given.

I tried to derive a general formula in terms of the given quantities using the sine and cosine rules, but it turned out that I need at least one more side.

If wanted, I will post my work, but I don't think it's worth it.

I am a high schooler so I have only a basic understanding of vectors and trigonometry.

Please leave a hint on how to proceed.

Comment: That's insufficient information to determine the sides.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown what else should be given sir ??

Comment: Think about rectangles, Atul.

Comment: @gerrymyerson sir quadrilateral is supposed to be scalene .. if I understood you correctly

Comment: Where does it say anything about the quadrilateral being scalene?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give 5 dimensions

4 sides, 1 diagonal

or

3 sides, 2 angles

or

2 sides, 3 angles.

One side , 4 angles given.. for such a case a construction gives a side with one parallel displacement degree of freedom.